# Is there some specific name for the function which take a complementary range of integration of standard normal cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions, notation

$$\phi_{2}(z):=\int_{-\infty}^{z}f_{\text{s}}(x)\,\mathrm{dx}\tag{1}$$

$$f_{\text{s}}(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\tag{2}$$

So$~\phi_{2}(z)~$represents the standard normal cumulative distribution function.

I wonder if there some name(s) for the following function which takes the complementary range of integration of$~\phi_{2}(z)~$

$$\phi_{}(z)=\int_{z}^{\infty}f_{\text{s}}(x)\,\mathrm{dx}\tag{3}$$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $\phi_2$ is not the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function). $\phi$ is sometimes called the [Q-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-function).

Comment: I see. Thank you.